# Process to solve for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm lost with the process to solve this equation.

$$38\sin\left(x-57.5\right)-66.6e^{-(\pi x)/(180\,\cdot\,1.57)}=30.$$

The exponential value for $x$ is in radians, thus I've converted to degrees. I have an answer of $200.5$ degrees, I'm just not sure how to get there.

The original question was

> (c) the extinction angle $\beta$ of the current (i.e. when it reaches zero after the input ac voltage becomes negative). Compare this angle to the pf angle of the RL load. ($200.55^\circ$)
>
> ANS: Solve $i(\omega t) = 38\sin\left(\omega t - 57.5^\circ\right) + 66.57 e^{-\omega t/1.57} - 30 = 0$
> numerically $\to \omega t = \beta = 200.55^\circ$

(screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWjg3.jpg )

Comment: $x$ has to stand for the same number throughout.  If you change one $x$ to radians, you have to change the other.  As it stands, it's not clear what your equation really is.

Comment: I would also consider it bordering on insanity to convert radians to degrees inside an equation like this. If you want to convert the final answer from radians to degrees, fine, but only as the last step. Perhaps you could show the equation as it was written before you started rewriting it.

Comment: Is there a missing $\,i\,$ factor in the exponent, maybe?

Comment: The equation is related to an electrical engineering problem. The angle is the extinction angle of current in a circuit with inductor, resistor and a battery. (I'm not sure if the details help much). Essentially the question is find the angle where the current goes to zero, and the equation I have provided is the time vaying eqation.

Comment: As for the radians, the x-57 is in degrees, thus I changed the exponential also.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a link to the question/solution I've been provided to give context.

Comment: By sticking in the extra 180, you've changed the equation.  Broken it, really.   Take the 180 back out and graph the left and right sides and see where they intersect.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've since been told the process in mind is iterative using the Newton Raphson method which is beyond the scope of my course to implement. I knew I wouldn't have been expected to do this question in an exam, but that didn't help cure the curious mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the original equation with the substitution $x = \omega t$ and with all angle values consistently stated in radians, which is the natural way to deal with angles in problems like this:
$$
38\sin(x - 1.0036) + 66.57 e^{-x/1.57} - 30 = 0.
$$

An equation like this has to be solved numerically.
Basically this comes down to "guess and check."
Newton-Raphson is just a sophisticated guess-and-check method with some formulas to help you make very good guesses.

The answer key claims the answer is $x = 3.5003$ (that is, $200.55^\circ$ converted to radians).
Let's try this:
\begin{align}
38\sin(3.5003 - 1.0036) &\approx 22.84 \\ 
66.57 e^{-3.5003/1.57} &\approx \phantom0 7.16 \\
38\sin(3.5003 - 1.0036) + 66.57 e^{-3.5003/1.57} &\approx 30
\end{align}

That looks about right.

You will not get this solution from the equation you wrote, however, because you changed one of your $+$ symbols to $-$ while you were converting things to degrees.

You can see other solutions of the equation by entering it in Wolfram Alpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=38sin(x-1.003564)%2B66.57e%5E(-x%2F1.57)-30%3D0

Interestingly, this gives two more roots near $x = 0.438.$
This may be an artifact of rounding that was performed when writing the equation. Even if it is not, the value of $i(\omega t)$ barely goes negative and does not stay negative very long at all.
So there is a question (which can only be answered by digging deeper into the original context of the formula) about why the lesser of these roots is not considered to be an "extinction angle".

Comment: Thanks for the answer!